# Рефакторинг юнит-тестов (Jasmine)

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты, jasmine, рефакторинг

При изменении бизнес-логики приходится прибегать к рефакторингу как кода так и юнит-тестов. В литературе по Jasmine рекомендуют использовать xdescribe (xit) блоки или функцию pending() для "пропуска" устаревших тестов. Подскажите как правильнее делать:

- использовать рекомендуемые методы (которые я перечислил выше)?
- удалять не нужные блоки describe (it)?

В чем преимущество и недостатки первого и второго подхода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если бизнес-логика изменилась, нет никакого смысла держать старые юнит-тесты в x-блоках. Если нужно будет посмотреть историю или восстановить что-то для этого есть git.

Comment: А для чего тогда нужны x-блоки?

Comment: В основном, чтобы временно закомментировать юнит тест.